# Android Overlay Camera Data in Background

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

In android, is that possible to overlay all camera data in background?

So overlay can be showed when user do Call over Skype, or Zoom? etc?

Maybe it will not be possible Main phone camera, how about USB Camera?

Just want to know if this is possible or not.